# Rails - undefined method `model_name' when calling edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to edit a page, while it tells it's not a variable from what I have known from related questions. In view, an error is raised from this line:

```
<%= form_for @wiki, :url => giki_path(@wiki.name), :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Where the @wiki does seem to be an instance, which can be confirmed by:

```
$ rails console
> @wiki
 #<Gollum::Page:70026260995800 Home (markdown) @wiki="path/to/git/wiki/.git">
> @wiki.name
"/wiki/Home"
```

So I don't understand what is causing the problem:

```
undefined method `model_name' for #<Gollum::Page:0x007f6084d2bdb0>
```

**Edit**:

In controller:

```
# giki_controller.rb
def edit
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
end

# the same method, worked fine
def show
  @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
end
```

In model:

```
# wiki.rb
class Wiki 
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :raw_data, :formatted_data, :title, :path, :change_desc, :versions

  # Gollum Init
  WIKI = Gollum::Wiki.new(Settings.wiki_repo, :base_path => "/wiki")

  # initialize
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      send("#{key}=", value)
    end
  end
  # no database
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def self.find(name)
    WIKI.page(name) # find a page by name
  end
```

First lines from logger:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `model_name' for #<Gollum::Page:0x007f607dfec4e8>:
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/model_naming.rb:9:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:47:in `dom_class'
```

**Full traceback**: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/KHN190/a8a9e8955334bbaddc9fd88f13f50823).

Comment: please provide the actual error message, unedited.

Comment: @toddmetheny traceback is too long. I use better_errors, in which the only prompted message is the undefined method line.

Comment: so do you actually call a method called `model_name` in your app? if so, please provide the code associated with that method call.

Comment: @toddmetheny I don't think so. It's implicitly somewhere in traceback. I'll update the code.

Comment: What does your `edit` action look like in your `WikisController`?

Comment: when do you get the error? when the page loads or when you submit?

Comment: It occurs when I load the page.

Comment: `giki_path(@wiki.name)` is this a valid path_helper?

Comment: @illusionist `rake routes` to check, yes. It is the path the form should post to.

Comment: Some more lines of `Backtrace` please, I want to understand which controller is accessing this view.

Comment: make sure `@wiki` is an instance of `Wiki` model

Comment: @illusionist `@wiki.instance_of? Wiki` return false. But not sure this check is correct. Since `@wiki.class` is `Gollum::Page`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108352/discussion-between-illusionist-and-knh190).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backtrace says that `model_name` is undefined in `<Gollum::Page:0x007f607dfec4e8>` which is an instance of `Gollum::Page`.

---

### Reason

`form_for` method internally calls `model_name` method. This is actually a valid method name in `ActiveRecord`'s instance.
Try

```
User.first.model_name
```

This `model_name` is not present in `@wiki` since this is not an instance of `Wiki` its rather the instance of `Gollum::Page`.

### How can I say that?

Well, I saw you have overridden the `self.find` method in `Wiki`

```
  def self.find(name)
    WIKI.page(name) # find a page by name
  end
```

so in your `edit` action, you have used `find` method to get the persisted instance, which will hand you over an instance `Gollum::Page` and this is not expected by `form_for` helper method.

### Solution (Edited)

Well, if you were using `ActiveRecord` and wanted to continue the overridden `self.find` method then you can use `where` or `find_by_x` method instead in `edit` action. Like

```
def edit
  @wiki = Wiki.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

But looks like you are not using `ActiveRecord` or your model is not derived from it, so you have to use the `form_for` method in different fashion.

If you don't need to attach a form to a model instance, then check out [ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper#form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

```
form_tag(giki_path(@wiki.name), method: :put)
```